# bash's brace-expansion didn't work

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

i have a simple problem with bash's brace expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash  
PICS="{x1,x2,x3}.jpg {y1,y2}.png"    
for i in $PICS  
do  
  echo $i  
done
```

but the result is:
{x1,x2,x3}.jpg
{y1,y2}.png
But i want the result is: x1.jpg x2.jpg x3.jpg y1.png y2.png
what should i do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The straightforward way is

```
#!/bin/bash  

for i in {x1,x2,x3}.jpg {y1,y2}.png; do
  echo $i  
done
```

Comment: Or `PICS=( {x1,x2,x3}.jpg {y1,y2}.png ); for i in "${PICS[@]}"; do ...; done`

Answer (score 3):

Brace expansion is performed while parsing the line, and will not happen inside quotes.

Comment: More generally, brace expansion is not performed on the RHS of an assignment, whether or not it is quoted; but brace expansion *is* performed for the values inside an array assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Brace and wildcard expansion is performed for arguments when a command is evaluated. Change the first line to:

```
PICS=$(echo {x1,x2,x3}.jpg {y1,y2}.png)
```

Answer (score 0):

These are files which already exist? If yes, you probably want a (ext)glob. E.g.

```
printf '%s\n' [xy]+([[:digit:]]).@(jp|pn)g
```

Brace expansion in Bash is the first expansion step. It occurs mostly in unquoted contexts, though the exact rules are complex. You cannot store one in a string unless you eval the result later.

```
printf '%s\n' {x{1..3}.jp,y{1,2}.pn}g
```

These can be defined however you feel. See other answers for less obfuscated options.

You also need to quote your expansions.